# minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, gulp

Trying to run the following command in laravel:

```
npm install --global gulp
```

but I get the following error : 
[image]

Comment: What is your question here ? Its a warning not error, because of lower version,as warning says.

Comment: I need the gulp file in my directory this should make it right?

Comment: what you get if you run `gulp -v` ?

Comment: [11:01:44] CLI version 3.9.1
[11:01:44] Local version 3.9.1

Comment: may be now you need to create your own `gulpfile.js` like [this](https://gulpjs.org/getting-started)